# Test set residual diagnostics and summary statistics for regression

Tags: regression, residuals

Is it not common in Statistics to perform residual diagnostics on out-of-bag data?

In (linear) regression software packages (like Python's statsmodels), the output of a trained model often provides summary statistics and residual analytics out-of-the-box for the data the model was generated on (in Machine Learning lingo, I would call this the training set). Examples are:

- $R^2$
- studentized residuals
- residuals in QQ-Plots

This functionality is usually reserved for the data the model has been created on. I.e. for data that has not been used in the calculation of the model ("test data", unseen data, out-of-bag data), software packages usually offer a "predict" method on a trained model, but not the full set of evaluation tools that are provided for summary statistics and residual analytics on the "training" set.

My question:

Is it not common in Statistics to perform residual diagnostics on out-of-bag data? Or is this just a shortcoming of the particular implementations that I have used?

Comment: It's not common, diagnostics are done on the training data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most classical software packages (and econometrics in general) were designed for model fitting and testing hypothesized relationships on a full sample of data and were never really meant to be tested out-of-sample. It is only rather recently that prediction has gotten so central to statistics, obviously owing to the rise of ML (and so much data that you can actually permit 20% to be used as a test). In general, it used to be highly unusual in at least academic empirical work to ever test a model out-of-sample. I think it is very illustrative that for example scikit learn in Python, which includes a Logistic Regression functionality, does not include some reporting tool on coefficients' significance (like the summary function in R does or the statsmodel in Python). They clearly serve different purposes.

In short - most 'academic' summary statistics on residuals will most likely only be available to 'train'-sample models because they fall in the classic model-fitting paradigm. Most 'predictive' model packages usually care less about statistical significance and the type of concerns for which one would evaluate statistical tests or statistics like you mention and 'just' want to predict well. Note all the quotation marks since I don't want to make any value judgement either way - they are just two different beasts..